# Securing MySQL id numbers so they are not sequential

Tags: mysql, md5

I am working on a little package using PHP and MySQL to handle entries for events. After completing an entry form the user will see all his details on a page called something like website.com/entrycomplete.php?entry_id=15 where the entry_id is a sequential number. Obviously it will be laughably easy for a nosey person to change the entry_id number and look at other people's entries.

Is there a simple way of camouflaging the entry_id? Obviously I'm not looking to secure the Bank of England so something simple and easy will do the job. I thought of using MD5 but that produces quite a long string so perhaps there is something better.

Comment: Can you check if the current user is allowed to see this specific page?

Comment: You can use GUIDs instead of auto-incrementing values as the primary key of your database table. With any system, you should be validating that the requested URL can be accessed by the person trying to access it. If you don't require a login, any URL can be accessed by anyone and even a GUID is just security through obscurity. When someone is logged in, you should verify if UserA can access `someID=4` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the users do have some form of authentication/login, use that to determine if they are allowed to see a particular entry id.

If not, instead of using a url parameter for the id, store it in and read it from a cookie.  And be aware that this is still not secure.  An additional step you could take (short of requiring user authentication) is to cryptographically sign the cookie.

Comment: I gave this answer the green tick as I thought use of a cookie was the most appropriate solution to my specific situation. On thinking more though, I didn't really want to go down the cookie route so I added the unix timestamp as an extra parameter. So now the user sees this url: website.com/entrycomplete.php?entry_id=15&timestamp=1622650197. The entry_id remains guessable, but the timestamp isn't. (I know it could be cracked by a determined person, but I'm just trying to stop nosey people, not make something bombproof.)

Answer (score 2):

[Security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) is no security at all.

Even if the id's are random, that doesn't prevent a user from requesting a few thousand random id's until they find one that matches an entry that exists in your database.

Instead, you need to secure the access privileges of users, and disallow them from viewing data they shouldn't be allowed to view.

Then it won't matter if the id's are sequential.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to implement this is to show only the records that belong to that user. Say the `id` is the unique identifier for each user. Now store both `entry_id` and `id` in your table (say table name is `entries`).

Now when the user requests for record, add another condition in the mysql query like this

```
select * from entries where entry_id=5 and id=30;
```

So if `entry_id 5` does not belong to this user, it will not have any result at all.

Coming towards restricting the user to not change his own `id`, you can implement `jwt tokens`. You can give a token on login and add it to every call. You can then decrypt the token in the back end and get the user's actual `id` out of it.